# Error mapping OneToMany or ManyToOne unmapped class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this problem :

Error creating bean with name 'ICustomerDao' defined in com.biblio.fr.biblio.repository.ICustomerDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.biblio.fr.biblio.entite.Book.loans[com.biblio.fr.biblio.entite.Loan]

this is my code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {
    private Integer id;

    private String title;

    private String isbn;

    private LocalDate releaseDate;

    private LocalDate registerDate;

    private Integer totalExamplaries;

    private String author;

    private Category category;

    Set<Loan> loans = new HashSet<Loan>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "BOOK_ID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Column(name = "ISBN", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    @Column(name = "RELEASE_DATE", nullable = false)
    public LocalDate getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(LocalDate releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "REGISTER_DATE", nullable = false)
    public LocalDate getRegisterDate() {
        return registerDate;
    }

    public void setRegisterDate(LocalDate registerDate) {
        this.registerDate = registerDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "TOTAL_EXAMPLARIES")
    public Integer getTotalExamplaries() {
        return totalExamplaries;
    }

    public void setTotalExamplaries(Integer totalExamplaries) {
        this.totalExamplaries = totalExamplaries;
    }

    @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAT_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE")
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    // @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.book", cascade =
    // CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Loan> getLoans() {
        return loans;
    }

    public void setLoans(Set<Loan> loans) {
        this.loans = loans;
    }

}

public class Loan implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 144293603488149743L;

    private LoanId pk = new LoanId();

    private LocalDate beginDate;

    private LocalDate endDate;

    private LoanStatus status;

    @EmbeddedId
    public LoanId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(LoanId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Column(name = "BEGIN_DATE", nullable = false)
    public LocalDate getBeginDate() {
        return beginDate;
    }

    public void setBeginDate(LocalDate beginDate) {
        this.beginDate = beginDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "END_DATE", nullable = false)
    public LocalDate getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(LocalDate endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    public LoanStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(LoanStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
@Embeddable
public class LoanId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3912193101593832821L;

    private Book book;

    private Customer customer;

    private LocalDateTime creationDateTime;

    public LoanId() {
        super();
    }

    public LoanId(Book book, Customer customer) {
        super();
        this.book = book;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.creationDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book bbok) {
        this.book = bbok;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE_TIME")
    public LocalDateTime getCreationDateTime() {
        return creationDateTime;
    }

    public void setCreationDateTime(LocalDateTime creationDateTime) {
        this.creationDateTime = creationDateTime;
    }
}
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
    private Integer id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String job;

    private String address;

    private String email;

    private LocalDate creationDate;

    Set<Loan> loans = new HashSet<Loan>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "JOB")
    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE", nullable = false)
    public LocalDate getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(LocalDate creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Loan> getLoans() {
        return loans;
    }

    public void setLoans(Set<Loan> loans) {
        this.loans = loans;
    }

}

public class Category {
    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String code, String label) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.label = label;
    }

    private String code;

    private String label;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Column(name = "LABEL", nullable = false)
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
@Repository
public interface ICategoryDao extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {

}
public interface ICustomerDao extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {
    public Customer findCustomerByEmailIgnoreCase(String email);

    public List<Customer> findCustomerByLastNameIgnoreCase(String lastName);
}
```

I can't see where is the problem of my oneTomany annotation
Anyone can, i help me.

Comment: Did you try adding `@Entity` to the `Loan` class?

Comment: Hello @Gustavo Passini , thanks a lot, i solve my problem by adding Entity to the Loan class